# Removing a certain marker in angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I am trying to remove a certain marker(when I click on it, it will pop-up an info-window and there I will have a delete button which will remove that marker from the map)

I also want that these markers to be kept in a localstorage to remain in the same position even if I refresh the page.

The problem is when I use slice method to delete the marker; this method will shift all my markers with one position so if I will add 3 markers named : Marker1, Marker2 and Marker3, and I want to delete Marker 2, the Marker3 will come instead of Marker2 position (replacing him) and I don't want that thing to happen. I want that all markers to remain in the same position.

I also tried not to remove the marker but to give it the null value but for that option the following error occurs:

> lat has no property of null

That is because when I loop with ***ngFor** through my markers, some markers will be null.

This is my component.html:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat"
      [longitude]="lng"
       [zoom]='zoom'
       (mapClick)="onMapClicked($event)">

  <agm-marker  *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index" 
           [visible]='m.visible'
          (markerClick)="onClick(m)"
          [latitude]="m.lat"
          [longitude]="m.lng"
          [markerDraggable]="m.draggable"
          (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd(m, $event)">

   <agm-info-window>

  <div class="eventText">
    <strong>{{m.name}}</strong>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
   (click)="onDelete(m)">Delete</button>
   </agm-info-window>

  </agm-marker>

 </agm-map>
```

This is my markerData.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { marker} from "./park.component";

@Injectable()
export class MarkerdataService {
markers: marker[] = [];

 constructor() { }
 getAllMarkers() {
 if (localStorage.getItem('markers') === null || 
   localStorage.getItem('markers') === undefined) {
   localStorage.setItem('markers', JSON.stringify(this.markers));
   return this.markers;
 }
 else {
   var markers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('markers'));
   return markers;
 }

}

addMarker(newmarker: marker) {

 var markers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('markers'));
 markers.push(newmarker);
 localStorage.setItem('markers', JSON.stringify(markers));

}


removeMarker(mark: marker) {

  var markers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('markers'));
  markers.splice(markers.indexOf(mark),1);
  localStorage.setItem('markers', JSON.stringify(markers));
 }


}
```

This is my component.ts:

```
export class ParkComponent {

 zoom: number = 10;
 lat: number = 44.458418;
 lng: number = 26.129007;
 private index:number = 0;
 private id:number = 0;
 markers: marker[] = [];

 constructor(private data: MarkerdataService){
   this.markers = this.data.getAllMarkers();
   console.log(this.markers);
   }

 ngOnInit(){}

 onClick(m: any) {
    console.log(m);
   }
 onMapClicked($event) {

   this.id++;
   this.index++;
   var newMarker:marker={
      id:this.id,
      name:'event: '+this.index,
      lat:$event.coords.lat,
      lng:$event.coords.lng,
      draggable:true
   }
   this.markers.push(newMarker);
   this.data.addMarker(newMarker);
  }
 onDelete(m:marker)
  {
   this.markers.splice(this.markers.indexOf(m),1);
   this.data.removeMarker(m);
  }

 }
export interface marker {
   id:number;
   name?:string;
   lat: number;
   lng: number;
   label?: string;
   draggable: boolean;
   visible?:boolean;
}
```

I have searched everywhere and I couldn't find a solution for that issue.

Thanks.